# Loading SVG to a canvas doesn't work

Tags: fabricjs

[As you can see the text should be placed where in the center and three lines where is highlited in yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZoZU.png)[And here is how it should be shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiG2X.png)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="485" height="620" viewBox="0 0 485 620" xml:space="preserve">
<desc>Created with Fabric.js 1.6.7</desc>
<defs></defs>
<g transform="translate(217 184) scale(2.31 2.31)">
<image xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,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" x="-75" y="-75" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" width="150" height="150" preserveAspectRatio="none"></image>
</g>
 <g transform="translate(216 189.03) rotate(333.15)">
  <rect fill="#ffff00" x="-51.11" y="-75.03" width="102.23" height="45.2"></rect>
  <rect fill="#ffff00" x="-32.97" y="-22.6" width="65.94" height="45.2"></rect>
  <rect fill="#ffff00" x="-83" y="29.83" width="166" height="45.2"></rect>
  <text font-family="Arial" font-size="40" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,255); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" >
   <tspan x="-51.11" y="-39.83" fill="#0000ff">TEXT</tspan>
   <tspan x="-32.97" y="12.6" fill="#0000ff">TO </tspan>
   <tspan x="-83" y="65.03" fill="#0000ff">DISPLAY</tspan>
  </text>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Hi i am loading a svg from a url to canvas but there's a problem with the text because is not placed correctly.Can anybody has solved this problem. Thank you

Comment: var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
fabric.loadSVGFromURL('image.svg', function(objects, options) {
  var obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
  canvas.add(obj).renderAll();
} and how can i share the svg if i pasted it here is too long and also some pics to shiw the result

Answer (score 0):

@Álvaro, please follow this

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
fabric.loadSVGFromURL('image.svg', function(objects, options) {
  var obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
  canvas.add(obj).renderAll();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer but that's exactly the code I'm using for tender a svg file, the problem I'm having its the text Is not placed right when i load the svg